# How can I use JavaScript to emulate Alt+Numpad functionality in Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, input, character

In Windows, we can press `Alt+Numpad` to enter characters.

For example, `Alt 244` is `⌠`.

I want to use javascript to realize this function.

By entering a number (like `244`) in the `input` textbox and clicking the button, the character would occur in the `output` textbox.

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var confirmButton = document.getElementById("Confirm");
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    confirmButton.addEventListener("click", clickConfirmButton);
    function clickConfirmButton() {
        // Please write here
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Alt+Numpad</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <div><label for="input">Input: </label><input style="height: 30px; font-size: 20px;" id="input"></div>
        <div><label for="output">Output: </label><input style="height: 30px; font-size: 20px;" id="output"></div>
        <div><button id="Confirm">Confirm</button></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried use `KeyBoardEvent` and `dispatchEvent` but there's nothing in the output textbox.

Please write only the javascript code and no jquery, html or css.

Comment: why don't you `// Please write here` what you've tried first - however, it's not going to work - you can of course just set the value of the input to any value you like without emulating keystrokes

Comment: @JaromandaX I misdeleted it... See if I can find.

Comment: don't bother, I realised what you are asking is impossible

Comment: @JaromandaX Why is that?

Comment: ALT+Numpad is handled by the operating system - a browser can't manipulate the operating system.

Comment: @JaromandaX Can't the browser wait for the result of the OS?

Comment: wait for what result? - the browser can't tell the operating system what keys are pressed, the operating system tells the browser (when it has keyboard focus) what keys a pressed

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is here: [Convert Unicode characters to extended ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636820/convert-unicode-characters-to-extended-ascii)

Also it's more interesting to update the output immediately and prevent typing characters but numbers in the input:

```js
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const output = document.getElementById("output");

input.addEventListener("input", 
  () => output.value = input.value ? String.fromCharCode(input.value) : ''
);

input.addEventListener("beforeinput", 
  e => e.data && (/\d+/.test(e.data) || e.preventDefault())
);
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
        <div><label for="input">Input: </label><input style="height: 30px; font-size: 20px;" id="input"></div>
        <div><label for="output">Output: </label><input style="height: 30px; font-size: 20px;" id="output"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I know that `String.fromCharCode` works because it just convert the `ASCII` to character. But I want to see if simulating `Alt+Numpad` is possible.

Comment: @SundayLi, but why do you *want to see if simulating Alt+Numpad is possible* - why complicate an easy process using a method that is unlikely to work - whatever you enter using "alt+Numpad simulation" can be done using the above code

Comment: I'm just curious...

Comment: Thanks for the solution(though I know how to do...)

Comment: @SundayLi you could try `String.fromCodePoint` or tell me what exact code you want to get what character and I will investigate...

Comment: @silentmantra I found that `String.fromCharCode` is not equivalent to `Alt+Numpad`

Comment: For example, you can try `244`.

Comment: @SundayLi https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636820/convert-unicode-characters-to-extended-ascii

Comment: @silentmantra I don't know how it can solve my problem...